# Eureqa Client to connect to Mathematica under Windows

Tags: packages, interoperability

Does there exist a way to use [Eureqa](http://creativemachines.cornell.edu/eureqa) software with Mathematica under Windows?
That is, is there a working client to connect to a Eureqa server?

Comment: I use Eureqa (aka Nutonian aka Formulize) _and_ Mathematica. But ... what kind of interoperability do you expect. And ... Who is "they" ?

Comment: I have used Eureqa and it's a nice tool, but I'm not aware of any Mathematica link. It's easy enough to copy the results from the Eureqa program manually. There is an easy API that you might try: http://code.google.com/p/eureqa-api/

Comment: A Mathematica client here:https://github.com/shanecelis/eureqa-mathematica-client

Comment: TC, I slightly rewrote your question to be less open-ended, to better fit with the expected Q&A format.  It is better to write a question seeking a single direct answer, than one that appears to be polling, e.g. "Do any of you..." etc.

Comment: You might also be interested in a similar program with very strong ties to Mathematica: http://evolved-analytics.com/?q=datamodeler/keyfeatures